# Как пишется класс советника?

Tags: числительные, наращение

Нужно ли наращение после числительного, обозначающего класс советника?

Грамота.ру [считает](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=206383), что наращение нужно, и допускает вариант с римскими цифрами:

- **советник 2-го класса**
- **советник II класса**

В [указе президента о порядке присвоения и сохранения классных чинов](http://www.consultant.ru/cons/cgi/online.cgi?req=doc&base=LAW&n=152609&div=LAW&dst=1000000001%2C0&rnd=0.08855431432227867) наращение не используется:

- **советник 2 класса**

По правилам порядковые номера требуют после себя наращения. Но есть исключения из этого правила. Например, капитанские ранги: **капитан 1 ранга**.

Не подпадают ли под это исключение классы у чиновников?

Answer (score 1):

Советник перво**го** (второ**го**, третье**го**) класса; капитан перво**го** (второ**го**, третье**го**) ранга; старшина перв**ой** (втор**ой**, треть**ей**) статьи — *падежные окончания "чиновничьих" числительных **зафиксированы**, они **неизменны*** (другими быть не могут), именно поэтому наращение и не используется.

Для сравнения (обычные порядковые числительные):
3-й класс, 3-му классу; 2-я статья, во 2-й статье.

В *[**Табели о рангах**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%85)* говорится:
*Генерал-адъютант состоял в 6-м классе (...), генерал-адъютант при генерал-фельдмаршале — в 7-м классе, генерал-адъютант при «генералах полных» — в 8-м классе. В дальнейшем чин генерал-адъютанта трансформировался в свитское звание, для получения которого необходимо было иметь военный чин не ниже 4-го класса.*

Но сейчас-то мы ТАК не говорим. Мы бы сказали: "Генерал-адъютант имел чин 6-го класса (или состоял в чине 6-го класса)".

Например (абстрактно):
На совещании в штабе присутствовали капитаны 1 [первого] и 2 [второго] рангов, а также старшины 2 [второй] и 3 [третьей] статей.
(Говорить "капитаны первых и вторых рангов, а также старшины вторых и третьих статей" — неверно.)

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно относить к исключениям числительное, не в полной мере являющееся порядковым. Ранги, степени, разряды и пр. определяют квалификацию и номинацию. При этом собственно число зачастую бывает прямо противоположно месту в ранжировании (например, как в случае со степенями орденскими).

По этой причине поддерживаю неиспользование наращения, но от применения римских цифр не отказывался бы. Они монументальны и не требуют наращения никогда.