# Наращения с классами школы

Tags: орфография, наращение

Был [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434192/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/435217#435217) о наращении в словосочетании "советник 2-го класса" (или II класса). Я же хочу спросить о школьных классах. Обязательно ли наращение или его можно опустить? Например:

*1 класс или 1-й класс?*

Понятно, что с наращением в любом случае не неправильно, но можно ли без него в этом случае?

Comment: Без наращения получается "один класс": *Сколько 5-тых классов в вашей школе? — Только 1 класс.*

Comment: Тогда лучше словом: один (всё-таки "класс" не единица измерения). И не 5-тых, а 5-х.

Comment: Но и "первый класс" можно словом. Думаю, что никаких исключений для слова "класс" нет и нужно действовать по общему правилу.

Comment: Ну да, "первый" **можно** словом, а можно и цифрой. А "один класс" **обязательно** словом.

Comment: В разговорном варианте необязательно)

Comment: Разговорный язык устный, а не письменный. :))

Comment: Не согласен. А как же передача "реальной" беседы между людьми в литературе? Иногда есть пересечение. И фиксация интервью. Да и банально переписка между людьми. Люди не переписываются литературно.

Comment: *Люди не переписываются литературно.* Ну как сказать. Я что-то слегка упрощаю, пишу с маленькой буквы предложения, не ставлю точку, если одно предложение, иногда опускаю кавычки, но цифрами не пишу больше, чем в других случаях. Мне это режет глаз. Передача беседы, фиксация интервью — согласен. Но у нас была речь о разной записи одного и того же по звучанию.

Comment: "пишу с маленькой буквы предложения, не ставлю точку" — неожиданно. Думал, что вы всегда принципиальны в грамотности. Я так никогда не делаю. Но цифрами - да. Это сокращает время. Но для точки или большой буквы треть секунды не жалко.

Comment: Мне видится за точками в простой переписке (не по электронной почте) холодность, когда одна фраза, не говоря уже о том, когда пишут одно слово и ставят точку. Тогда особенно. Предложения начинаю с маленькой, но имена собственные всегда пишу с большой. Названия могу и не начинать с большой, например фильма, а кавычки по-разному.

Comment: Есть такое. Больше строгость. Строгость в языке переходит в ощущения. Но правила это не разрешают, даже в переписке)))

Comment: И что, есть правила, по которым надо писать: "ok.", "Да.", "Нет.", "Хорошо." и т. д.?!

Comment: Но это одно слово как предложение. Не может же быть слов вне предложений. Но разве что в словаре - перед значениями. Но это просто слово как факт - вне какой-либо мысли.

Comment: Вообще я согласен, но никакой нужды в этой точке не вижу в таких случаях в обычной-то переписке. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 класс или 1-й класс?**

В правилах пишется, что следует использовать форму **1-й класс**. Но можно обратить внимание на то, что это правило для школьных классов часто нарушается.

В частности, на обложках школьных учебников  наращения не делаются, о чем уже были вопросы: https://korrektor-ru.livejournal.com/941189.html

Соответственно, наращения не всегда делаются и в других случаях, например: все учебники для 5 класса. Возможно, это упрощенная запись.

Вопрос № 227219

При оформлении условий заданий для школьной олимпиады верно писать **«9 класс», «11 класс»** (как здесь: http://www.gramota.ru/olimpiada.html?id=272) или все-таки «9-й класс», «11-й класс» и т. д.?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка:  Согласно общему правилу наращение нужно: *9-й класс, 11-й класс*. В приведенном тексте наращение не использовалось, чтобы не перегружать текст.